# Can't get hold of command line arguments

Tags: assembly, printf, nasm

I am very new to assembly but I already have ran into a problem. This is the start of my code. printf prints just constant 2 no matter what the argument is.

```
section .data
msg: db "n = %d ",10,0

section .text
global _main  
extern _printf   


_main:

push ebp
mov  ebp, esp
sub  esp, 16

push DWORD [ebp +8]
push msg    
call _printf
```

I was told commandline arguemnts were supposed to be +8,+12 and so on from the pointer, but this doesn't work. Right now it just prints n=2.

Comment: Why not set a breakpoint on main and then take a look at the stack on entry, then single step through your code and see what is actually happening?

Comment: Is it possible you've got hold of argc instead of argv?  (They would both have to be 8-byte things, but I suppose that's possible.)  Easy way to check would be to give two command line arguments and see if "3" magically appears.

Comment: You are printing the number of arguments which is always `number_of_arguments+1`. So if you put one agrument you always get "n = 2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it shoud print the number of arguments and the first argument

```
section .data
msg: db ""nbargs = %d, 1st argument = %s",10,0

section .text
global _main  
extern _printf   

_main:

push ebp
mov  ebp, esp
sub  esp, 16

mov  eax,dword ptr [ebp+12]
mov  ecx,dword ptr [eax+4]
push ecx
mov  edx,dword ptr [ebp+8]
push edx
push msg
call printf
...
```

If your program is called myprog, you shoud for example get this output:

```
myprog myargument
nbargs = 2, 1st argument = myargument
```

Comment: This works as intended. This made assembly memory pointing and location a lot clearer. Thanks